# Runing App in Simulator(IOS) i am getting this issue

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am attaching below what error i am getting

[ERROR] :  certificate has expired
2017-10-14T05:46:30.298Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 100
2017-10-14T05:46:30.299Z | ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 100
    at ChildProcess. (/Users/balakrishna/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:92:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
2017-10-14T05:46:30.300Z | TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  2240

Comment: Please add the version of your CLI/SDK/appc/node (run `appc info`)

Answer (score 1):

Update your CLI/dev environment: `appc setup && appc use latest`